# Multiple options not staying selected after saving

Tags: php, html, options, select

**Problems:**

The save works, but is only storing one of the options in the database after save.

Options not showing as selected after save.

The select fields:

```
<select id="exclude_page_from_cookies" name="exclude_page_from_cookies[]" multiple="multiple">
        <?php

        $pages = get_pages();
        foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
            $title = get_the_title($page);
            $id    = $page->id;
            ?>

            <option id="<?php echo $id; ?>" value="<?php echo $title ?>" <?php selected( $title ); ?> >
                <?php echo $title;?>
            </option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </select>
```

The save function:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['exclude_page_from_cookies'] ) ) {
    foreach( $_POST['exclude_page_from_cookies'] as $exclude_page ) {
         echo $exclude_page;
         update_option( 'exclude_page_from_cookies', $exclude_page ) ;
    }
}
```

I understand I have already posted this in regular stack exchange, but since this is a WP thing I figured I'd move it here :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to save the value as an array because you want multiply items to be selected. The `update_option` function will serilized an array for you so you only need to give it an array of items. In your code you saving over all the items because you use the same key `exclude_page_from_cookies` and not as an array. You also need to mark the selected item as selected to be able to save more items. The function `selected` needs an `selected` and `current` to match and echo the selected tag. You save the value as the title but i recommend that you save it as the ID of the page, because if you have the ID you can easily get the title by using the function `get_the_title()`. So i updated your save function to accept arrays:

```
$exclude_pages = $_POST['exclude_page_from_cookies'];

if( isset( $exclude_pages ) ) 
{
   update_option( 'exclude_page_from_cookies', $exclude_pages );
}
else
{
   delete_option( 'exclude_page_from_cookies' );
}
```

And your selected box markup:

```
<select id="exclude_page_from_cookies" name="exclude_page_from_cookies[]" multiple="multiple">
       <?php
          $pages = get_pages();
          $exclude = get_option('exclude_page_from_cookies');

          foreach ( $pages as $page ) 
          {
          ?>
             <option value="<?php echo $page->ID; ?>" <?php echo ( in_array( $page->ID, $exclude ) ? 'selected' : '' ); ?> >
                <?php echo $page->post_title; ?>
             </option>
          <?php
          }
       ?>
    </select>
```